# how may i set a domain name to point to many subfolders in xampp?

Tags: xampp

Actually I have many sub folders inside htdocs directory each folder contain an `index.php` file and have a separate action.

How may I set my domain name so it will be pointing to all of these sub folders?

Lets say i have `c:\server\ht docs\folder1`, `c:\server\ht docs\folder2` and so on. I would like my domain name to act like `localhost`. When typing `www.domain name.com/folder1` it will take me to `c:\server\folder1` and so on for all of the folders.

I tried with `localhost` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

- Edit the windows "host" file located in
  `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`as an administrator.
- Add the following line in the host file and save it:

  > 127.0.0.1 www.domain_name.com

**Step 2:**

- Open the "httpd-vhosts.conf" file located in
  `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra`

Add the below lines and save.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.domain_name.com
 ServerAlias www.domain_name.com
 DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

Now restart apache server using XAMPP Control Panel

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve using VirtualHost configure or redirect URL

Comment: Can u say in details how may i resolve to many subdirectories at once pls?
So www.domain name.com/folder1 will take me to folder one and so on for folders 2,3...

Comment: please check it, httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html  :)

Answer (score 0):

All the answers about adding domain to xampp subfolders are missing some steps, so I'll add mine which is more or less complete.

0. If you've changed `httpd.conf` or `httpd-vhosts.conf` files, return them to default. Specifically, in `httpd.conf` make sure your `DocumentRoot` points to default location, we will instead use `vhosts` file to point domains to different subfolders each:

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/"
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/>
```

1. in `httpd.conf` file (main apache config) find and uncomment:

   `#Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to: `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
2. in `etc/extra/httpd.vhosts` file, add your domain and specify its `DocumentRoot` (That should be one of the folders in `htdocs`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.ge
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/example-landing-testing"
    ServerName example.local
    ErrorLog "logs/example.testing-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.testing-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

2. in your system's `hosts` file, add the following:
   `127.0.0.1  example.local`
3. restart apache
4. no need to restart system

Optional: If you're running xampp in WSL, you will also need to modify windows's hosts file to point to WSL's IP:

1. Open notepad as administrator
2. Open file: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
3. In wsl terminal instance, run this handy command to get its IP:
   `ip addr show eth0 | grep 'inet\b' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1`
4. Add IP to hosts file:
   `172.20.13.40 example.local`
5. Save, no need to restart system